# Having trouble with Final Cut Pro disk space

Tags: macos, storage, disk-space, final-cut-pro

When I try to load footage onto final cut pro, it says that i do not have enough disc space. Before I start loading, I have 320 GB of free space.
In total, I am trying to load 5 hours of footage.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for posting a question! Can you please post a screenshot of the error so we can help you?

Comment: What version of Final Cut Pro are you using? Where are your scratch/temp/cache files located, and how much disk space is available on that volume?

Answer (score 1):

.DV tends to be about 4MB/sec. So 5 hours is about 18,000 seconds, so you are looking at a capture of about 72000MB, 72G so you should be fine..

Are you sure the Capture Scratch disk is set properly? Sometimes it's set to the wrong drive you want to capture to.

Check Preferences if you are using FCP, if you are using FCPX it might be somewhere else, not sure how you set capture disks in FCPX..

Answer (score 0):

I found that System settings- Minimum allowable free space on scratch disks:
Set mine to 1000MB and everythng has worked since doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, here's how I solved it:

1. Close all Libraries from the file Menu
2. Quit FCPX
3. Restart the Mac
4. Open the Library in Finder by command+click and "Show Package Content"
5. Manually copy any file into the library (It doesn't matter what you copy, this is just in order to change the size of the package.)
6. Open FCPX using Command+Option to reset settings
7. try to import something new

if it works you can safely remove the files you added in step 5. This seems to be a bug that causes FCPX to confuse the library's file size with the available disk space, once you forcefully change the numbers it snaps out of it and resumes working normally. 
Hope this helps someone, because this bug drove me up the wall for an eternity before I figured out the work around.